# How to implement Find-on-Page command in MFC web browser control with pre-filled search word?

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, mfc

I'm using the [MFC web browser control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046(v=vs.85).aspx) in my dialog-based MFC project to display some HTML content and I am trying to make it show the "Find on page" dialog window with the search word already pre-selected in it. (What you'd get if you hit Ctrl+F in the IE web browser.)

If I do the following the find dialog is shown OK, but it doesn't seem to support a way to pre-fill the search word:

```
IWebBrowser2* pWebBrowser = NULL;
LPUNKNOWN unknown = m_browser.GetControlUnknown();

unknown->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2,(void **)&pWebBrowser);

if(pWebBrowser)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CComVariant varNull;
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr = pWebBrowser->ExecWB(OLECMDID_FIND, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, &varNull, &varNull)))
    {
        //Success!
    }

    pWebBrowser->Release();
}

if(unknown)
{
    unknown->Release();
}
```

I found [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691264(v=vs.85).aspx), that says:

> **OLECMDID_SHOWFIND** Tells the receiver to show the Find dialog box. It
>   takes a VT_DISPATCH input param.

So evidently there's another Find command with `OLECMDID_SHOWFIND` ID, but I can't seem to make it work. I don't understand what is this `VT_DISPATCH` input param either? When I try this -- a total shot in the dark due to the lack of documentation:

```
CComVariant var1 = L"Pre-filled search word 1", var2 = L"Pre-filled search word 2";
hr = pWebBrowser->ExecWB(OLECMDID_SHOWFIND, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, &var1, &var2);
```

but I get `hr=0x80040100` or `"Trying to revoke a drop target that has not been registered"`

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: dude, I asked it over 6 years ago. I honestly don't remember. All I can tell you is that IE is so buggy. If you can use Chromium engine instead.

Comment: I know it long time ago. Chromium is lacking way to many features to be useful to me. I have the find dialog working with minimum code but sometimes it stops working. As in if I recreate the page in same browser control and invoke ctrl f and type it finds no text. I have to shut the control down and display again for it to function properly.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: I don't remember exactly, but I think I created my own modeless dialog and used it instead.

Comment: I'm curious what features is Chromium lacking?

Comment: The print dialogue is not as efficient. The page settings are lacking functionality.

Comment: For example when a control is only part of your app and you do print preview it gets squished into the control area. Iexplore sensible allowed us to preview full screen. And you can close your app even when print dialog is visible. The page settings can’t be customised unlike in iexplore.